# Test to ensure the user input is a double and is greater than zero?

Tags: c#, parsing, while-loop, user-input

In C# I am trying to have the user input a number. I then want to check that

1. They have entered a string that can be converted to a double and
2. They have entered a value greater than zero

The method I have initially created was

```
string inValue;
double outcome;

Console.WriteLine("Enter amount: ");
inValue = Console.ReadLine();
while (double.TryParse(inValue, out outcome) == false)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Initial value must be of the type double");
    Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter the number again: ");
    inValue = Console.ReadLine();
}
outcome = double.Parse(inValue);
while (outcome < 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Initial value must be of at least a value of zero");
    Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter the number again: ");
    inValue = Console.ReadLine();
    outcome = double.Parse(inValue);
}
return outcome;
```

The problem was this was that if the user entered say "-10" and then "f" an exception would occur. This is because the program would move past the first check (that checks for the double) for the value of -10 but then when the "f" is entered it throws an exception when only given the second test.

I believe the solution is to create a while statement that writes the error statement when either the value cannot be converted to a double or the value is converted to a double and is below zero. What I don't know how to do is to have the value be converted to a double and then evaluated as being greater than zero all in the while statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're on the right track - you need to have a single while loop that gets the input and then tries both validations.  One way to do this is to create a boolean value that tracks whether or not the value is valid, and then use that as the condition for the loop:

```
double outcome = 0;
bool valid = false;

while (!valid)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter amount: ");
    string inValue = Console.ReadLine();
    if (double.TryParse(inValue, out outcome) == false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Initial value must be of the type double");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter the number again: ");
    }
    else if (outcome < 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Initial value must be of at least a value of zero");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter the number again: ");
    }
    else
    {
        valid = true;
    }
}
return outcome;
```

It's also possible to put both conditions in the while statement, but this approach lets you provide a different message depending on which conditions failed.

Comment: It is more idiomatic to use `!condition` instead of `condition == false`. I understand you kept the code as similar to the original as possible, but I'm just pointing out for future reference.

Answer (score 6):

you can or those two conditions in your first while loop

something like

```
while (!double.TryParse(inValue, out outcome) || outcome < 0)
{
    ...
}
```

some explanation: double.TryParse will modify the value of outcome if it is successful, so if it was able to parse then the ! TryParse will be evaluated to false, thus we get to the second part and evaluate outcome < 0.

Comment: The question though is what will be `...`. Using your approach, how he will form the error message?

Comment: @IvanStoev Initial value must be a double and greater than zero

Comment: That's possible, but not equivalent of OP.

Comment: @IvanStoev in his last sentence it is clear that the OP wants to do it all in one while statement isn't it.

Comment: `if (outcome < 0)
 Console.WriteLine("Initial value must be of at least a value of zero");  
Console.WriteLine("Initial value must be of the type double");  Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter the number again: ");`

Comment: If the value must be greater than 0, then the second condition must be `outcome <= 0`. Use an error message that explains both conditions: "The initial value must be a double greater than 0".

Comment: @MikeDebela What if zero was invalid? In general, BJ Myers answer is the right way. It allows you to perform as many validations as you wish and provide different error messages.

Comment: @IvanStoev it really depends on what the OP want the error message to look like. You can definitely put both conditions in one message.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with a solution like this. Just noting that you don't have to `double.Parse(Value)` after you have done a `double.TryParse(value, out outcome)` the out parameter will populate that variable upon the TryParse being true.

You can copy and paste the below code into [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and play with it. But this does what you need.

```
void Main()
{
    var result = DoWork();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

public double DoWork()
{
    string inValue;
    double outcome;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter amount: ");
    inValue = Console.ReadLine();
    while (!double.TryParse(inValue, out outcome) || outcome <= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Initial value must be of the type double and greater than 0");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter the number again: ");
        inValue = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    return outcome;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

after a little regrouping it is working code!
but i think you sometimes need to use if instead of while

```
    string inValue = "";
    double outcome = -1;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter amount: ");
    while (outcome < 0){
      inValue = Console.ReadLine();

      if (double.TryParse(inValue, out outcome) == false)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Initial value must be of the type double");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter the number again: ");
        continue;
      }
      if (outcome>=0) {continue;}
      Console.WriteLine("Initial value must be of at least a value of zero");
      Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter the number again: ");
    }
    return outcome;
```

Comment: Downvoted for 1) not removing the redundant call to double.Parse and 2) awful, *awful* indentation.